# Javascript image upload (Non framework)

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to upload image(s) via JavaScript (Non framework). Does anyone have a basic example of how to this?

I get this error message:

> Warning: Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in Unknown on line 0 Array ( )

Here is what I'm working with so far.

```
<form action="" method="" enctype="" id="uploadImage">
<input type="file" name="image1" id="image1" value="" >
<input type="button" id="submit_button" data-data_enctype="multipart/form-data"     data-form_name="uploadImage" data-url="/gallery/images/upload/" data-change_div="getForm"  value="Upload" onclick="image(this.id, form.id)"/>
</form>

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

var datVar = document.getElementById(id);
var url = datVar.dataset.url;
var change_div = datVar.dataset.change_div;

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById(change_div).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xmlhttp.send('NULL');
```

Comment: I dont see you adding the form data anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data that you want to send to the xmlhttp.send() method. Currently you are passing it 'NULL' so it complains that the data is missing.

Something like 
`var data = document.getElementById('#uploadImage');`
gets the form.
create a FormData object (FormData is only supported in modern browsers)
`var formData = new FormData(data);`
and then passing `formData` to the send method should do.